# Using --add-host or extra_hosts with docker-compose

Tags: docker, hosts, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` to run a test environment, that consists of about 5 different containers. The inter-container links and the shared volumes (volumes-from) works wonderfully. I also expose some ports up to the host machine, which works nicely.

What I am missing is a way to link some of my real servers into this environment, without hardcoding ip address. With `docker run`, you could use `--add-host` to add another line in your `/etc/hosts` file. Is there any way to do something similar with docker-compose?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This works still `docker-compose` 1.3 with `extra_hosts` parameter:

```yaml
rng:
  build: rng
  extra_hosts:
    seed: 1.2.3.4
    tree: 4.3.2.1
```

Comment: For any one finding this to error out saying unsupported config directive "extra-hosts" it's not "extra-hosts" it's "extra_hosts".

Comment: The format here, of a nested dictionary, is out of date.  This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61231167/1497199 is more up to date.

Comment: @Dave No, it is NOT out of date. If you should have the wrong format, docker-compose will tell you: `services.imageproxy.extra_hosts contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or an array`. And `object` is one of two options. Far preferrable to a string, IMHO.

Comment: i have added this `extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`

but still it is saying in logs that connection refused

Answer (score 170):

https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#extra_hosts

> **extra_hosts** - Add hostname mappings.
> Uses the same values as the docker client --add-host parameter.

```
extra_hosts:
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
 - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

> *An entry with the ip address and hostname will be created in /etc/hosts > inside containers for this service, e.g:*

```
162.242.195.82  somehost
50.31.209.229   otherhost
```

Comment: Not supported on build

Comment: How can I map an external name (not an IP) to a container alias?

Comment: You mean set a hostname?  
-h HOSTNAME
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Or use an alias in docker-compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases

Comment: `extra_hosts` appears to be supported as an undocumented subkey of `build`, at least on compose 2.4.1.

Comment: It should be also supported on build now: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/build.md#extra_hosts

Comment: Will I be able to use this for DinD (Docker in docker) by borrowing the host docker sock connection via this syntax?

Answer (score 109):

Basic `docker-compose.yml` with [extra hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
api:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "5003:5003"
    extra_hosts:
        - "your-host.name.com:162.242.195.82" #host and ip
        - "your-host--1.name.com your-host--2.name.com:50.31.209.229" #multiple hostnames with same ip
```

The content in the `/etc/hosts` file in the created container:

```
162.242.195.82  your-host.name.com
50.31.209.229   your-host--1.name.com your-host--2.name.com
```

You can check the `/etc/hosts` file with the following commands:

```
$ docker-compose -f path/to/file/docker-compose.yml run api bash  # 'api' is service name
#then inside container bash
root@f7c436910676:/app# cat /etc/hosts
```

Comment: IMHO this should be the top answer -- the other higher-voted answers are a bit out of date.