# docker-compose chrome-alpine to use nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, google-chrome-headless, docker-network

I have this docker-compose configuration in which I want to embed a chrome headless browser to run my e2e tests...

The `nginx` is configured to reverse proxy a url, let's say `foo.bar` to somewhere...
this works just fine if I use my host browser, and I can test it by exposing the `444:443` ports!

however, it doesn't work when I try to use the `chrome-alpine` one, 
I navigate to the debugger `localhost:9222`, select the instance and then type: `http://foo.bar`.

How can I configure `alpine-chrome` to use the nginx container?

```js
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    command: [nginx-debug, "-g", "daemon off;"]
    volumes:
      - ../../config/nginx/nginx.config.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
      - ../../config/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - "444:443"

  chrome:
    image: zenika/alpine-chrome:latest
    command: [chromium-browser, "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
    ports:
      - "9222:9222"
```

#### Expected

1. Navigate to `localhost:9222`
2. Open the Chrome remote debugger
3. type the url `foo.bar`
4. have nginx reverse proxy `foo.bar` to (e.g.) `google.com`

Comment: You want to access chrome through nginx ?

Comment: I'd like to type `foo.bar` on the chrome debugger and then have it resolved by `nginx`

Comment: `foo.bar` is in your host's `/etc/hosts` when you do it ok on host chrome?

Comment: yes, exactly... I have it on my `/etc/hosts` on my computer, so from my laptop's chrome it works just fine... the issue arises when I use the chrome-alpine

Comment: i was going to tell the same as @atline mentioned, you need to add it inside /etc/hosts of the container, through docker-compose use `extra_hosts` keyword this will allow the chrome container to resolve the domain name points to the container ip

Comment: the chrome container? `foo.bar:localhost`? I tried but didn't work out

Comment: I guess your format is wrong.

Comment: yup, I should be typing a ip address but they are dynamically assigned...

Comment: have you tried as 127.0.0.1 ? /etc/hosts expects an ip not something to resolve, what do you mean by dynamically assigned ?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work... could you provide an example?

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541426/2336650 , it should be `foobar: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: What's the `foo.bar` point to in /etc/hosts on hosts?

Comment: just tried, it doesn't work... nginx doesn't receive any request... I added the extra host to the chrome image and by inspecting it I can see `127.0.0.1 foo.bar` I think `127.0.0.1` should be the ip of the nginx container instead... and that's why I said it is dynamic

Comment: Could you try updated answer, add `container_name`, and also add extra hosts, foo.bar points to the container_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work by defining a static IP for the nginx container like below:

> Note: The purpose of setting a static IP for nginx is to avoid any issue that could happen due to ip changes.

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    command: [nginx-debug, "-g", "daemon off;"]
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      nginx-chrome-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1

  chrome:
    image: zenika/alpine-chrome:latest
    command: [chromium-browser, "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
    ports:
      - "9222:9222"
    networks:
      - nginx-chrome-network
    extra_hosts:
      foo.bar: 172.28.1.1


networks:
  nginx-chrome-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Then by going to `localhost:9222` and opening a new tab then typing `foo.bar` you will get same as the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome @Hitmands, due to ssl issues, is it a self signed certificate ? as it works with google's website correctly, if you are using a self signed certificate you need to `Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors` in DevTools

Comment: yeah, it is self signed, issue solved by starting chrome with `"--ignore-certificate-errors", "--reduce-security-for-testing",` flags

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity I did not find a simple solution after trial, I guess @Mostafa Hussein 's static ip solution is the simplest one to realize the requirement.

The result from my investigation is to alias `foo.bar` as `127.0.0.1`, and let `socat` to forward `127.0.0.1` network traffic to `mynginx`, here, `socat` could use `mynginx` which could not be used in `extra_hosts:`

So, my solution is next, ugly but in case anyone need it later:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mynginx
    command: [nginx-debug, "-g", "daemon off;"]
    ports:
      - "444:443"

  chrome:
    image: zenika/alpine-chrome:latest
    container_name: mychrome
    command: [chromium-browser, "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
    ports:
      - "9222:9222"
    extra_hosts:
      - "foo.bar:127.0.0.1"

  helper:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    volumes:
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
    tty: true
    command: bash -c "docker exec -u root -it mychrome /bin/sh -c \"apk add socat && socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:mynginx:80\""
    depends_on:
      - chrome
```

And the test:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/99$ docker exec -it mychrome wget -q -O - http://foo.bar
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like you have to pass valid ips to `add_hosts`: `Cannot create container for service chrome: invalid IP address in add-host: "nginxproxy"`

Comment: If possible we first narrow down issue with `remove extra_hosts related, but set container_name=foo.bar`, and in browser we just input `http://foo.bar` to see if it's ok, then we try to find other solution?

Comment: Seems an interesting question, I will try in local to simulate your situation.

Comment: A pity I did not find a simple solution, just use `socat` to forward the traffic from `127.0.0.1` to `mynginx` is my result. I think @Mostafa Hussein solution to use static ip is good, also upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `links` under your `chrome` container and call `nginx` by nginx:port :

```
links:
   - nginx
```

or you can use network driver `host` for both container and call each othe by localhos:port

```
network: host
```

the network config  shoud be under each service, also see [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)

Comment: can you add more details? (Especially for the `network` option) since `links` has been deprecated

Comment: I don't think I can use the `host` network since I'd need to override the `/etc/hosts` on the ci then...

Comment: Linking between containers wont solve the issue as generally `foo.bar` wont be identified by the docker network anyway, it works if the container named `foo.bar` inside the docker network itself