# can't connect mongodb on host from docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

I have a mongo on my host machine, and an ubuntu container which is also running on my machine. I want that container to connect to mongo.
I set as host url, my host ip from docker network : **172.17.0.1**
and in the **/etc/mongod.conf** file I set the bindIp to **0.0.0.0**

from  the container, I can ping the host,but the mongo service is not accessible, I get that error :

```bash
Connecting to:          mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.5.0
MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
```

More over, I can connect from host to the mongo service with that command :

```bash
mongosh mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017
```

Do you know why I can't access mongo service from my container ?

Comment: Check my answer for a proper solution. Better late than nothing ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: warning]
Do not use `0.0.0.0` to bind a socket on your host. It can be a security issue. It's the way to declare all IP are able to connect to `mongodb` from any host.

Better edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and add the `docker` interface ip, like:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1
```

Then, in the `docker run`, you can add a host:

```
docker run --add-host mongohost:172.17.0.1 <CONTAINER>
```

Now, in your container, you can query `mongohost` on port `27017`.

**This is the clean solution.**

You can also use [`extra_hosts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541426/465183) if you use `docker-compose`.

But, **Docker Compose is primarily designed for local development and testing purposes**.

According to the official [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/), if you insist to use it, use V2 and a special `production.yaml`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `host.docker.internal` as reference to your host machine from the container. So `mongo host.docker.internal:27017` should work.

From docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/):

> I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and does not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop.

**This solution is not provided for every `docker` environments. `docker desktop` have this feature unlike basic Linux environment.**

Comment: same problem :/

Comment: @patacoing Edit your question and show how you are running your container with all options, etc. If your container is set up correctly, this answer is correct.

Comment: Edited post, this solution is not working outside of docker desktop. See my answer

Answer (score -1):

On your local machine that has Mongo service is running, you can access by Mongo client because you expose the service at `127.0.0.1:27017`.

However, it is not true if standing from your `unbuntu` container, there is no Mongo service is running at `172.0.0.1:27017` of the `ubuntu` container.

[Docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is the right tool for you to make containers communication to each other.

Comment: Anything Docker Compose can put together so can Docker. Using Docker Compose is a good tool but by itself does not solve the problem.

Comment: But 172.17.0.1  refers to my host machine, so there should be a mongo service running

Comment: @JohnHanley: `172.17.0.1` is typically the ip of the `docker` interface by default, so it's the ip of the host. See my full answer.

Comment: @GillesQuénot - Thank you for the feedback. +1 for your answer that mentions security with a good solution.

Comment: Not really a solution, no example, moreover, not the cleanest way. Sorry but voted down.