# Facing 500 Internal Server Error in Dockerized Laravel Microservices When Connecting to MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, docker

I've been working on a Laravel microservice application, which I've containerized using Docker. Most of my endpoints work seamlessly both inside and outside the container. However, when my application tries to connect to MongoDB (especially for transactional queries), I consistently get the error: `There is no active session.`, which originates from MongoDB\Driver\Exception.

Here's what I've confirmed so far:

- MongoDB replica set is set up correctly.
- The application connects and operates perfectly with MongoDB outside the Docker environment.
- All services and dependencies are running, and network configurations seem correct, as other endpoints in the same container work without any issue.

Here is a snippet from my Dockerfile for reference:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-alpine AS php
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    autoconf \
    build-base \
    libpng-dev \
    oniguruma-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    imagemagick-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    unzip \
    openssl \
    zip \
    freetype-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-webp --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql opcache gd zip \
    && pecl install swoole-4.8.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable swoole

# Stage - Production Image
FROM php:8.0-alpine
# Install runtime system dependencies for PHP extensions
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libpng \
    imagemagick-libs \
    libzip\
    libgomp \
    freetype \
    jpeg \ 
    libwebp \
    libstdc++
COPY --from=php /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY --from=php /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
COPY --from=php /usr/lib/ /usr/lib/
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["php", "artisan", "octane:start","--port=8000", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

And the error log from Docker:

`500    POST /master/login ................................. 23.35 mb 30.81 ms`

Has anyone encountered this before or can provide some insight into what I might be missing or doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### Update

The issue was the MongoDB. Everything working fine now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't connect mongodb on host from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109508/cant-connect-mongodb-on-host-from-docker-container)

Comment: I've already check that post, but it's different.

Comment: You're installing MongoDB, but where is it started ?

Comment: MongoDB is outside the container.

Comment: Do you mind sharing in which way your case is different? There is nothing in the question to answer.  If you read it without context of your working environment, it literally says "I do everything right, but it doesn't work". 500 is a generic server error, and the "log" conveys no information but how much memory was used and how quick the request was. You get "There is no active session."  from somewhere. At least post the full error traceback.